# Filter SQL Columns against an entire columns contents?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I need to filter an entire table against all the VARCHAR's in a different table. I've thought of just grabbing them in a foreach loop but I'd be conducting that for each row. It's a large database and can return upwards of 10k results so I figured that'd be bad because it'd take a while to return the data.

My main thought is to do that filtering in SQL to speed things up a bit more instead. My only other thought is to just grab the data from the initial table, throw it in an array, then check as a string each datatable row value against that whole array in C#.

Speed isn't really a priority, but it just can't be unacceptable. I'm concerned about going through with the stuff in the first paragraph because it may be strenuous on the users computer. Could someone tell me how I can make that a bit more efficient? Or will that be my only option in SQL?

Comment: A simple join will do what you need. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If you data and your filter are both in the database, and you don't use SQL to filter one against the other, you shouldn't be using a database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `exists`.  Something like this:

```
select b.*
from bigtable b
where exists (select 1 from smalltable s where s.string = b.string);
```

For performance, be sure there is an index on `smalltable(string)`.